# Unable to update some of the attributes using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I'm trying to create new attribute and populate it, but for unknown reason some of the features does not update while others are updated normally.

```
  # scores - list of values which length is equal to the number of features in layer.

  score_att_name = 'F_SCORE'
  caps = self.layer.dataProvider().capabilities()
  if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddAttributes:
      res = self.layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(score_att_name, QVariant.Double)])
  self.layer.updateFields()
  feats = self.layer.getFeatures()
  att_id = self.layer.fieldNameIndex(score_att_name)
  self.layer.startEditing()
  i = 0
  for feat in feats:
      score = scores[i]
      attrs = {att_id: score}
      fid = feat.id()
      self.layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({ fid : attrs })
      self.layer.updateFeature(feat)
      i += 1
  self.layer.commitChanges()
```

There are no `NULL`/`None` values in `scores` and number of items in it corresponds to the number of features in layer. It is expected either for all the features to get non-NULL values in the newly created attribute or get `NULL` for all of them (if there is an error in code).

Here is the `scores` content:

```
[-0.1924320401655787, -0.3011441017990289, -0.16252774237448944, -0.30138576399544564, -0.30200044628243455, -0.2779783498269975, -0.2420625175170869, -0.295068402157225, -0.2976507832929624, -0.2140032879792433, -0.29832468774549037, -0.29723224511785584, -0.28129089378239636, -0.2894700697069985, -0.16974038814535744, -0.25809302976180065, -0.2988300443409982, 0.0917123519767264, -0.26583612088822345, 4.94647318248023, -0.29526096086609877, -0.21327671122718667, -0.2823017044646275, -0.2580216656881462, -0.23932206565124473, 0.1411220021301911, -0.2874893152592108, -0.3036300172774237, 3.692289329980737, -0.2726130899249829, -0.3021985904055799, -0.3030091219894229, 0.1411220021301911, -0.29398722839889163, -0.29541202867082983, -0.25634338249136523, -0.018893864443287018, -0.2935667830438211, 0.40979414662628333, -0.2945805319935501, -0.16338703660469128, -0.30414800204438525]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be all you need:

```
feats = self.layer.getFeatures()
self.layer.startEditing()

for feat in feats:
   score = scores[i]
   feat['F_SCORE'] = score
   layer.updateFeature(feat)
self.layer.commitChanges()
```

You are mixing update via the layer vs at the provider.  Generally you should only update via the layer as it provides rollback and error handling at a higher level